# How do I get rid of problem with values in input?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have `post.title` and `post.body` in value, and I need that after changing the values in the text inputs, it is saved in data so that I can use these new values later for the user to write (`PUT` request) on the API. How can I achieve this?

[image: Screenshot the of the app]

Here's my code -

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <input type="text" v-model="createTitle" />
        <input type="text" v-model="createBody" />
        <button @click="addPost()">AddPost</button>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(post, index) of posts">
                <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
                <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
                <button @click="deleteData(index, post.id)">Delete</button>
                <button @click="visiblePostID = post.id">
                    Изменить
                </button>
                <transition v-if="visiblePostID === post.id">
                    <p><input :value="post.title"><br><input :value="post.body">
                        <button type="button" @click="changePost(post.id, post.title, post.body)">Применить</button></p>
                </transition>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'app',
    data() {

        return {
            posts: [],
            createTitle: '',
            createBody: '',
            visiblePostID: '',

        }
    },
    changePost(id, title, body) {
        axios.put('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id, {
            title: title,
            body: body
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @Riddhi's answer, you could use `v-model` on those inputs with temporary variables so that the model is not modified until the `PUT`-request is confirmed successful:

1. Add temporary data properties to hold the `<input>` values from the template:

   ```
   // template
   <transition v-if="visiblePostID === post.id">
     <input v-model="tmpTitle" />
     <input v-model="tmpBody" />
   </transition>

   // script
   data() {
     return {
       tmpTitle: '',
       tmpBody: ''
     }
   }
   ```
2. Replace the edit-button's handler with a method (named `editPost()`), and pass to the method the current post's ID, title, and body, which will be stored in the temporary data properties declared above:

   ```
   // template
   <button @click="editPost(post.id, post.title, post.body)">
     Изменить
   </button>

   // script
   methods: {
     editPost(id, title, body) {
       this.tmpTitle = title;
       this.tmpBody = body;
       this.visiblePostID = id;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Update `changePost()` to also take the current `post`, which will be updated with the temporary data properties once the `PUT` request is successful.

   ```
   // template
   <button type="button" @click="changePost(post, post.id, tmpTitle, tmpBody)">
     Применить
   </button>

   // script
   methods: {
     async changePost(post, id, title, body) {
       const { status } = await axios.put("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + id, { title: title, body: body });
       if (status === 200 /* HTTP OK */) {
         post.title = title;
         post.body = body;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/p386n0p12q?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 2):

For two-way data binding you should use `v-model`. Read [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage).

```vue
<transition v-if="visiblePostID === post.id">
  <p>
    <input v-model="post.title">
    <br>
    <input v-model="post.body">
    
    <button type="button" @click="changePost(post.id, post.title, post.body)">Применить</button>
  </p>
</transition>
```